# How can I capture a future YouTube livestream between two points in time?

Tags: youtube, video-streaming

Suppose I know that a certain YouTube channel will have a live-stream item in the future, between time points t_1 and t_2 (known to me). I have no trouble scheduling things to happen on my system at time point t_1 (and at t_2) - using `at` or `cron`; but what I don't know how to do is how to do the actual timed capture, and how to notice the stream on the webpage (it's always the main item on the channel page).

What's the easiest/best way to achieve this?

**Notes:**

- I'm using Linux.
- I don't mind writing a short script.
- I don't mind about missing a couple of seconds (but I'd rather minimize that of course).

Answer (score 2):

If the user is using the "stream now"-feature, you can simply access it via `youtube.com/channelURLhere/live`, and recording a stream can be done via any screen recording tool really, there ought to be a couple in your repo – if in doubt VLC or OBS should do the job.

That said, YouTube automatically saves all live streams up to 12 hours, though the streamer may chose to make the recordings private and delete them later. You can ask them to keep it public or unlisted instead.

Comment: I'll try your first suggestion (the second suggestion is not relevant in my case).